# Not JSON or YMAL. Which data format is this?

Tags: json, serialization, yaml, json-deserialization, dataformat

need help to understand following format, Which data notation format is this? any clue,

data format sample,

```
SCHEMA 
 user="AAA" time=1235789008 /* "23-Jun-2018 02:09:14" */
{
  /* comment - data*/
  VERSION=4
  TITLE=Test
}
```

Comment: Please look up how to [format code](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code). We need to see exactly how the code looks, and as the question currently looks, that is unclear.

Comment: Doesn't look like anything to me. Can you give some information on the context? Probably some exotic homebrew format.